# Big O Notation basics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Having some problems with big O notation question... getting confused on how to figure this out.

I'm working on a problem (exam coming up so doing extra ones) where it asks us to arrange the functions in a list so that every function is big-O of the next.

$$2^{100n}, 2^{n^2}, 2^{n}, n\log n, \log \log n, n^{\frac{1}{2}}, n(\log n)^{1/2}, n^{4/3}(\log n)^2$$

Big O is extremely confusing to me so I don't know where to start..

edit: fiddling around with Latex, please bear with me!

Comment: To be clear, you should add "as $n \to \infty$" to the question.  And do not use notations like ${=}_a$ or $\prec$ unless your instructor already did.

Comment: unfortunately, the question didn't mention any of that. thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 2):

$f=_a O(g)$ simply means the quotient $\dfrac fg$ is bounded in a neibourhood of $a$ (except perhaps at $a$ itself).

Here, the functions are classified by the fact that $f=_a o(g)$, i.e. $\dfrac fg\to 0$ when $x\to a$, and noting that $f=_a o(g)$ implies $f=_a O(g)$ . Thus by classical results, we have, in increasing order:
$$\log\log n \prec n\log n\prec n^{3/2}\prec n^{4/3}\log^2n\prec 2^{100n}\prec 2^{n^2}\prec2^{n!}$$

Comment: Your "200" should be $2$.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for pointing the typo.

Comment: where does $2^{2^n}$ land? I assume it will be in between the last two terms?

Comment: There's no $2^{2^n}$ in your list! But yes, it would be between the last two terms.

Comment: ah my apologies. it's supposed to be there but nevermind =) thanks!